# Using C# and Lambda, how to get a distinct list from a property of a nested List<>?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, distinct

I have a List<> of objects that contains another List<> of objects and I'm trying to get a distinct list of values from a property of the nested List<> object. Is there a clean Lambda way of doing this?

```
class Order
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
    
// create a list of all orders from today.
List<Order> orders = GetOrders(DateTime.Now);

// i know this is way wrong, but hopefully expresses what I'm trying to do.
List<string> productIds = orders.Products.Distinct(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0). I think this will work for you.

```
List<string> productIds = orders.SelectMany(o => o.Products).Select(p => p.ID).Distinct();
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Thanks for the link as well, was helpful seeing all the other methods available.